# In Python I need to do an iterative groupby that access the previous "grouped value" to establish the value of the row of the aggregated column

Tags: python, pandas, loops, group-by, iteration

I have the following dataset that you can replicate with this code:

```
number_order = [2,2,3,3,5,5,5,6]
number_fakecouriers = [1,2,1,2,1,2,3,3]
dictio = {"number_order":number_order, "number_fakecouriers":number_fakecouriers}
actual_table = pd.DataFrame(dictio)
```

[image]

What I need is to write a code that through a for loop or a groupby generates the following result:

[image]

The code should perform a groupby on the column "number_orders" and then take the minimum of the column "number_fakeorders", but each time it should iteratively exclude the minimum values of the column "number_fakeorders" that have been already selected. Then in case there are no more values available it should input a "None".

This is the explanation row by row:

**1) "number_orders" = 2 :** here the value of "number_fakeorders" is "1", and it is simply the minimum value of "number_fakeorders", where ["number_orders" = 2], because it is the first value that appears

**2) "number_orders" = 3 :** here the value of "number_fakeorders" is "2" because "1" has been already selected for ["number_orders" = 2], so excluding "1", where ["number_orders" = 3] the minimum value is "2"

**3) "number_orders" = 5 :** here the value of "number_fakeorders" is "3" because "1" and "2" have been already selected

**4) "number_orders" = 6 :** here the value of "number_fakeorders" is "None" because the only value of "number_fakeorders" where ["number_orders" = 6] is "3", and "3" has already been selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
def fn(x, seen):
    for v in x:
        if v in seen:
            continue
        seen.add(v)
        return v


out = (
    actual_table.groupby("number_order")["number_fakecouriers"]
    .apply(fn, seen=set())
    .reset_index()
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
   number_order  number_fakecouriers
0             2                  1.0
1             3                  2.0
2             5                  3.0
3             6                  NaN
```

---

Note: You can sort dataframe before processing (if not sorted already):

```py
actual_table = actual_table.sort_values(
    by=["number_order", "number_fakecouriers"]
)

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop the `groupby` object and record previous min value in each group

```py
res, prev_min = [], set()

for name, group in actual_table.groupby('number_order'):
    diff = set(group['number_fakecouriers']).difference(prev_min)
    if len(diff):
        m = min(diff)
        prev_min.add(m)
    else:
        m = np.nan

    res.append([name, m])

out = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=actual_table.columns)
```

```
print(out)

   number_order  number_fakecouriers
0             2                  1.0
1             3                  2.0
2             5                  3.0
3             6                  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```
u = df['number_order'].unique()
d = {v:k for k,v in enumerate(u)}

(df.loc[df.sort_values('number_fakecouriers').groupby('number_order')['number_fakecouriers'].cumcount().le(df['number_order'].map(d))]
.drop_duplicates('number_fakecouriers')
.set_index('number_order')
.reindex(u)
.reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   number_order  number_fakecouriers
0             2                  1.0
1             3                  2.0
2             5                  3.0
3             6                  NaN
```